# Tensorflow Basic text classification exercise

Tags: python, keras, text-classification

I'm trying to complete the exercise for the basic text classification from tensor flow and I'm getting the following error when I try to run model.fit using the stack overflow data set. I've followed the exercise instruction to the letter and I think I understand the exercise, I just don't get it why the error is occuring. The only thing I can think of is that vectors are of different length somehow?

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 4) and (None, 1) are incompatible
```

my code is below and the error happens in the last line shown:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import re
import shutil
import string
import sys
import pathlib

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import losses
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras import utils

from pathlib import Path

print(tf.__version__)

url = "http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data"

dataset = tf.keras.utils.get_file("stack_overflow_16k.tar.gz", url,
                                    untar=True, cache_dir='stack_overflow_16k',
                                    cache_subdir='')

dataset_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(dataset))

train_dir = os.path.join(dataset_dir, 'train')
os.listdir(train_dir)
batch_size = 32
seed = 42

raw_train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'train', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='training', 
    seed=seed)

raw_val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'train', 
    batch_size=batch_size, 
    validation_split=0.2, 
    subset='validation', 
    seed=seed)

raw_test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.text_dataset_from_directory(
    'test', 
    batch_size=batch_size)

def custom_standardization(input_data):
  lowercase = tf.strings.lower(input_data)
  stripped_html = tf.strings.regex_replace(lowercase, '<br />', ' ')
  return tf.strings.regex_replace(stripped_html,
                                  '[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation),
                                  '')

max_features = 10000
sequence_length = 250

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    standardize=custom_standardization,
    max_tokens=max_features,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=sequence_length)

train_text = raw_train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x)
vectorize_layer.adapt(train_text)

def vectorize_text(text, label):
  text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)
  return vectorize_layer(text), label

train_ds = raw_train_ds.map(vectorize_text)
val_ds = raw_val_ds.map(vectorize_text)
test_ds = raw_test_ds.map(vectorize_text)

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

train_ds = train_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
test_ds = test_ds.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
embedding_dim = 16

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Embedding(max_features + 1, embedding_dim),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D(),
  layers.Dropout(0.2),
  layers.Dense(4)])

model.summary()

model.compile(loss=losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=[tf.metrics.Accuracy()])

epochs = 10
history = model.fit(
    train_ds,
    validation_data=val_ds,
    epochs=epochs)
```

Thanks in advance for all your help, worth noting is that I'm a complete begginer :p

Comment: Is this a binary classification problem? If so, try changing Dense(4) to Dense(1)

Comment: Hi, it's not a binary classification problem, I have 4 different categories so I have left Dense(4).

Comment: In that case, can you check the shape of your labels? It might help to add an example of the labels that you're using. I'm thinking it could be that your labels are in the wrong shape (i.e. a list of length 1 instead of 4)

Comment: Hi I have 4 labels and when I print this:

`print("Label 0 corresponds to", raw_train_ds.class_names[0])`
`print("Label 1 corresponds to", raw_train_ds.class_names[1])`
`print("Label 2 corresponds to", raw_train_ds.class_names[2])`
`print("Label 3 corresponds to", raw_train_ds.class_names[3])`

The result is as follows:

`Label 0 corresponds to csharp`
`Label 1 corresponds to java`
`Label 2 corresponds to javascript`
`Label 3 corresponds to python`

Comment: Sorry I meant the actual shape of the label data, not the label names themselves

Comment: Hi, I ran the 'label_batch.numpy' command and got the following:
<bound method _EagerTensorBase.numpy of <tf.Tensor: shape=(32,), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3,
       3, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1])>>

Is the shape then an array of dimension 1?

Comment: Yes correct, you only have one label per row here. This is then a multiclass problem i.e. you can have any number of labels, but only one label per row. You should try one-hot encoding your labels, so that each row will be i.e. [1,0,0,0] for 1, [0,1,0,0] for 2 etc, i.e. shape 4